# How to delete GCP Storage notification programmatically?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

In my bash script I want to recreate GCS notification create by:

```
gsutil notification create -f json -t <topic> -p <prefix> gs://<bucket>
```

In case I'll try to call this line again, it will create one more (the same) notification.

In order to delete the notification I need:

```
gsutil notification delete projects/_/buckets/<bucket>/notificationConfigs/<config-id>
```

`config-id` is the identifier returned when the notification is created. also, it can be retrieved with:

```
gsutil notification list gs://<bucket>
```

The output of `list` call is similar to:

```
projects/_/buckets/<bucket>/notificationConfigs/<config-id>
        Cloud Pub/Sub topic: projects/<project>/topics/<topic>
        Filters:
                Object name prefix: '<project>'
```

This `config-id` does not look like something to parse easily in Shell.

Is there a normal way to manage notifications? Or can I create notifications with no duplicates (so the second `create` call will not create a new notification, but update the existent)?

Answer (score 2):

If you use the CLI, it's the normal way. If you use the debug command, you have a id field, but not sure that the response be easier to parse

```
gsutil -D notification list gs://<bucket>
```

You can also use the [REST API of Google Cloud Storage for the notifications](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/notifications#resource)

In the list endpoint, you have a notification description with the ID of the notification, easy to get this time.

Finally, you can use the client library (here in [Python for example](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/notification.html)) where you have handy method, like an Exist, to be sure to not create twice the same subscription.